# server error in application the resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working at an ASp.net mvc 3 project and
 I keep getting this error and can find any help to solve the problem

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) 
could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.      Please       review  the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

  Requested URL: /RoomType
```

But I have The RoomType controller and  in my Global.asax I have:

```
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
      {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
     null, // we don't need to specify a name
     "Page{page}",
           new { Controller = "Room", action = "List" }
```

);

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Room", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            null, // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Room", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
           null, // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "RoomType", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
```

Here is my RoomTypeController :

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
     using System.Data.Objects;
       using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;
     using MvcApplication4.Models;

     namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
    {
    public class RoomTypeController : Controller
    {
    private hotelEntities db = new hotelEntities();

    //
    // GET: /RoomType/

    public ViewResult Index(int start = 0, int itemsPerPage = 20, string orderBy = "RoomType_ID", bool desc = false)
    {
        ViewBag.Count = db.Room_Type.Count();
        ViewBag.Start = start;
        ViewBag.ItemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
        ViewBag.OrderBy = orderBy;
        ViewBag.Desc = desc;

        return View();
    }

    //
      // GET: /RoomType/GridData/?start=0&itemsPerPage=20&orderBy=RoomType_ID&desc=true

        public ActionResult GridData(int start = 0, int itemsPerPage = 20, string orderBy = "RoomType_ID", bool desc = false)
        {
        Response.AppendHeader("X-Total-Row-Count", db.Room_Type.Count().ToString());
         ObjectQuery<Room_Type> room_type = (db as   IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Room_Type>();
        room_type = room_type.OrderBy("it." + orderBy + (desc ? " desc" : ""));

        return PartialView(room_type.Skip(start).Take(itemsPerPage));
    }

    //
    // GET: /Default5/RowData/5

    public ActionResult RowData(int id)
    {
        Room_Type room_type = db.Room_Type.Find(id);
        return PartialView("GridData", new Room_Type[] { room_type });
    }

    //
    // GET: /RoomType/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("Edit");
    }

    //
    // POST: /RoomType/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Room_Type room_type)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Room_Type.Add(room_type);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("GridData", new Room_Type[] { room_type });
        }

        return PartialView("Edit", room_type);
    }

    //
    // GET: /RoomType/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Room_Type room_type = db.Room_Type.Find(id);
        return PartialView(room_type);
    }

    //
    // POST: /RoomType/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Room_Type room_type)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(room_type).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("GridData", new Room_Type[] { room_type });
        }

        return PartialView(room_type);
    }

    //
    // POST: /RoomType/Delete/5

    [HttpPost]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Room_Type room_type = db.Room_Type.Find(id);
        db.Room_Type.Remove(room_type);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to give more information. Is this when running the app from Visual Studios web server or in IIS? If IIS, is it 6 or 7? Did it work before when the controller was "Home"? Also, you dont specify the routes in the "web config", you do it in the Global.asax

Comment: Yes before when my controller is Room http://localhost:51757/Room it work but then when i try to go to http://localhost:51757/RoomType i get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your controller class is called `RoomTypeController` (and not `RoomType`, and not `RoomController`) and that it contains an `Index` action:

```
public class RoomTypeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in there, should be return View();

Comment: No worries, you already helped me several times. It's the least I can do ;)

Comment: In my RoomType controller I dont have ActionREsult Index but i have ViewResult index could that be the problem ?i put the code from Room TYpe Controller up in the question

Comment: No, that's not the problem although it's a good practice to always use the highest possible class in the object hierarchy which in this case is ActionResult. Do you have some other route definitions that in your `RegisterRoutes` method that you haven't shown? Also probably a stupid question but did you recompile the project after modifying your route definitions?

Comment: Oh no. Those routes are completely incompatible. They all follow the same pattern `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. That's impossible. When you define a route it's because it has some specific url pattern. You should have kept the default route that was generated by the wizard when you created the application instead of creating 3 identical routes. It would have worked with both `/Room` and `/RoomType` urls.